# PHP is overwriting itself when imploding an array

Tags: php

so I have the weirdest problem that I've ever seen.

So, some background, I have a class that contains trades, with wants, haves, and the user who wants to trade. I also have a print method, that shows it as a node in the form of (Want | have1, have2, etc..), but when I implode the haves array, it overwrites it.

Here's an example:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
" string(14) "Draconnection
  [1]=>
" string(19) "Cyber Angel Idaten
  [2]=>
" string(12) "Hitodenchak
  [3]=>
" string(13) "Bujingi Warg
  [4]=>
" string(10) "Rai Rider
}
-Rai RiderargIdaten
```

And Here's my class code

```
class trade{
    protected $have;
    protected $want;
    protected $user;
    function __construct($want,$have){
        if (is_array($have)){
            $this->have = $have; // have is an array of strings
        }else{
            $this->have = [$have];
        }
        $this->want = $want; 
    }
    function getHave(){
        return $this->have;
    }
    function getWant(){
        return $this->want;
    }
    function __toString(){
        // return "(".$this->want." | ".implode(",", $this->have).")\r\n";
        // var_dump($this);
        $out=implode("-",$this->have);
        var_dump($this->have);
        return $out;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean it overrides it?

Comment: @Adrián "overwrite", not override.

Comment: What do you mean it overwrites it?

Comment: Read the guidelines on how to make a question in Stackoverflow.

You put the code but you don't put the var_dump().
Also what debugging have you made so far?

Comment: I've tried reprinting it in different ways, The var dump shows that it's a regular array, and by overwriting I mean that each successive concat that implode should be doing is actually printing over the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have rogue metacharacters at the end of all of those strings, probably bare `\r`s. The string data is all there, but the thing that's printing it keeps getting a command to return to the beginning of the line before printing more data overtop of the previous.

If you've got a shell handy run `php yourscript.php | hexdump -C` to see the raw output where `0d` not followed by `0a` is a bare `\r` not followed by a `\n`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I fixed it by reading it line-by line, I think the problem was the fact that I was splitting it by \n, so it was leaving the \r's behind, I had no clue they could have that kind of effect.